# Pandas resample -> apply first partition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

Is it somehow possible to use the pandas `resample` method and subsequently only use the first (or any specific) partition for an apply (or any other method in that regard)?

To illustrate:

```
def do something(x):
    return [x]

my_timeseries.resample("d").apply(do_something)[0]
```

Now this gives me the output I desire but also calculates it for all other partitions as well (obviously) but if I wanted to select the first partition from the resampled object only, it will automatically take its mean and give a warning:

```
my_timeseries.resample("d")[0].apply(do_something)

>> FutureWarning: 
.resample() is now a deferred operation
You called __getitem__(...) on this deferred object which materialized it into a series
by implicitly taking the mean.  Use .resample(...).mean() instead
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some fiddling I got a not so nice, but working, solution, if anyone else is interested:

```
resampler = my_timeseries.resample("d")
my_timeseries[resampler.indices[list(resampler.indices)[0]]].apply(do_something)
```

This way we get the indices of the "grouped" items that the resampler object contains and can make use of those to select them in the original `Series`.

**Note:** this likely only works for python 3.6+ (I haven't actually tested it with lower versions) since it requires the indices dict to be ordered, which is the case, starting from 3.6, where it is only an implementation detail, but should be a guaranteed specification starting with python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of pandas the method `DataFrame.resample` used the parameter `how` for down- or re-sampling, with `mean` as the default for downsampling (check the documentation of the version 0.17 [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample))

Now, the method returns a resampler object, which has to be explicitly manipulated to do the down/upsampling. This is what raises the FutureWarning and implicitly call the `mean` before indexing the data.

When you use `my_timeseries.resample("d").apply(do_something)[0]`, you employ `do_something` to resample the data and then access the element `0`.

On the other hand, directly indexing `my_timeseries.resample("d")` is not possible and, for compatibility reasons, pandas call `mean` before indexing. The best you can do is to use `my_timeseries.resample("d").apply(do_something)[0]` as you said.